# Библиотека для работы с JSON для iOS

Tags: xcode, objective-c, ios, json, библиотеки

Нашел следующие библиотеки:

- `SBJSON`
- `JSON kit`
- `Touch JSON` (как я понял устарел и не поддерживается)

хочется поинтересоваться что пользуется бОльшим успехом и какие особенности этих библиотек. И возможно какая лучше.

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться, для каких конкретно задач с JSON вы хотите использовать эту библиотеку?

Comment: закачка и парсинг

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Советую выбирать Вам между `NSJSONSerialization` и `JSONKit`. Про разницу между ними ничего особенного не скажу, обе библиотеки делают свое дело.

Что касается их производительности, то разница у них незначительная (JSONKit быстрее, но не намного) и к тому же редко когда вы столкнетесь с тем, что именно производительность разбора JSON будет для вас bottleneck. Смотрите на эту тему очень [поучительный комментарий автора библиотеки RestKit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13965675/598057).

Единственный довод за `NSJSONSerialization` - это отсутствие лишней зависимости от сторонней библиотеки (я имею в виду зависимость от JSONKit в случае, если вы выберете её), хотя, если вы пользуетесь [Cocoa pods](http://cocoapods.org/), этот довод становится совсем еле заметным.

Довод против `NSJSONSerialization` и в пользу `JSONKit` - это что `JSONKit` удобнее в использовании - я пользуюсь `JSONKit` главным образом из-за того, что она добавляет удобные категории к классам `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSString`. И вместо того, чтобы писать каждый раз заново строки NSJSONSerialization типа

```
NSJSONSerialization *yourResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:yourData options:0 error:&jsonError];
NSArray *yourObjects = (NSArray *)yourResponse;
```

При использовании JSONKit Вам достаточно будет написать

```
NSArray *yourObjects = yourData.objectFromJSONData;
```

На мой взгляд это удобно и незаметно. Настолько незаметно, что я даже не сразу вспомнил какой JSON-библиотекой я пользуюсь, когда прочитал Ваш вопрос.

**ОБНОВЛЕНО ПОЗЖЕ**

Мой взгляд на этот вопрос изменился с тех пор, как я отвечал на него полтора месяца назад. Сейчас я бы советовал использовать исключительно родной NSJSONSerialization.

Вот несколько причин:

1. JSONKit, похоже, накрепко заброшен автором. Xcode 5 выдаёт очень много Warning'ов по поводу JSONKit, как он есть, и автор никак не реагирует на соответствующие репорты (если интересно, см. многочисленные issues вроде [#121](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/pull/121) в его репозитории на Github).
2. Вот эти [Тесты производительности на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218583/jsonkit-benchmarks) показывают, что NSJSONSerialization работает быстрее или как минимум наравне с JSONKit (начиная с iOS 6).
3. Если вы используете для работы с сетью AFNetworking, то он за кулисами разбирает JSON с помощью NSJSONSerialization, и вам вообще не нужно думать о том, какой JSON парсер выбирать и использовать, так как за вас всё уже сделано и вы получаете готовые свои ответы уже завернутые из JSON в NSDictionary/NSArray.

Кратко: используйте NSJSONSerialization!

Comment: Сделал значительное обновление своего ответа! Советую всем, кто подписан на этот топик, ознакомиться.

Answer (score 1):

Мне нравится `NSJSONSerialization`, вполне самодостаточен, и да чутка не удобен.
Очень нравится `KISSXML` к нему есть категории расширяющие работу с `JSON` и `XML`.
ну и я за `JSONKit`

[Сравнение](https://github.com/bontoJR/iOS-JSON-Performance)